# Why is my auth.log file empty?

Tags: ssh, logging, ubuntu-14.04, login

I have an ubuntu 14.04 server running a service, and I'm currently setting up some logging visualization, but I noticed my /var/log/auth.log is empty.

I assumed it wouldn't have much since I've disabled ssh connections other than using an ssh key.  But, I did expect there to be sshd logs.  Is there somewhere else that I would see the logins using ssh keys, or is there something else happening I'm unaware of?

My ultimate goal is to have a log of every time someone tries to login using the key, or without the key.

---

**EDIT1**

I see that there are auth.log backups, but they aren't recording ssh attempts, or successful ssh logins using keys.  They only show CRON jobs.

I also elevated the sshd_config logging level to VERBOSE instead of INFO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Ubuntu systems [rsyslog](http://www.rsyslog.com/) handles system logging, redirecting output from several daemons (such as sshd) to their respective logs according to its config.

There are several config files that could affect the usage of the log file. I would start by debugging rsyslog, first checking its [config](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/rsyslog.conf.5.html) at **/etc/rsyslog.d** (more likely, 50-default.conf) and looking for a line that *should* look something like this:

```
auth,authpriv.*         /var/log/auth.log
```

If it's not set up to **/var/log/auth.log**, then you just found the problem, the output is going somewhere else. If not...

Next, check that **rsyslog** *is actually running* with `systemctl status rsyslog`, if it's not, it is possible something disabled it or it's not even present as a service, you can re enable (if it's there) the daemon with `systemctl enable rsyslog`.

Also, your [sshd config](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/sshd_config.5.html) could be either disabling logging completely or overwriting rsyslog's configuration, check for `SyslogFacility` inside your **sshd.conf**, which could be redirecting the messages to **another rsyslog facility,** by default it should be `AUTH` (as the line in the first step config). Of course, `LogLevel` is also important, but you got it in `VERBOSE`, so that shouldn't be the problem.

For debugging sshd, you could try putting it on debug mode with `-d`, as stated on [man](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/sshd.8.html):

> Debug mode.  The server sends verbose debug output to standard error, and does not put itself in the background.  The server also will not fork and will only process one connection.  This option is only intended for debugging for the server.  Multiple -d options increase the debugging level. Maximum is 3.

Be **careful** while tweaking sshd if you are on a sshd connection as you could, of course, end up locked off the remote machine.

Comment: Thanks for your incredibly detailed and thorough answer.  In my case, rsyslog was disabled for some reason.  Thanks again,

Answer (score 4):

Another reason could be wrong ownership of the file.

Check the ownership of the file - /var/log/auth.log

If it's not owned by syslog:adm , then change it to syslog:adm

sudo chown syslog:adm /var/log/auth.log

This fixed the issue for me in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

If you have no rsyslog, it may be because your ubuntu is "minimized", and you usually see this message at login:

> This system has been minimized by removing packages and content that are
>   not required on a system that users do not log into.
>
> To restore this content, you can run the 'unminimize' command.

So just run `unminimize` and confirm.

Comment: Thought I'd add a comment here so that users that use ScaleWay and their ubuntu dist could have a more easy time to find this comment (took me a while as I actually didn't know they ran minimized images!). Thanx for this answer! :)